# Visual Studio 2013 RTM Ultimate not installing giving error Failed to install core features fatal error

Tags: visual-studio

I have tried to install the Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 RTM from ISO downloaded from the MSDN and an error occurred during the installation. It states that Installation failed to install core features and fatal error. Even when I try the web installer the result is same.

Here is the error log file http://pastebin.com/MagY7R80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1303 ErrorMessage: Error 1303.The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2\Catalogs\VisualStudio12\IndexStore. The installation cannot continue. Log on as administrator or contact your system administrator.

This is the error in the error log so I tried to give the folder Full Permissions from security tab in properties... this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not running the installer as Administrator, or you do not have sufficient privileges to the specified folder, please refer to this line in your log:

1303 ErrorMessage: Error 1303.The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory: **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2\Catalogs\VisualStudio12\IndexStore**.  The installation cannot continue.  Log on as administrator or contact your system administrator.

Comment: I am the admin and I have all admin previliges

Answer (score 0):

To solve this try the following:

- Open Setup as Administrator
- Extract the ISO and then Run the setup
- If nothing worked reinstall the OS 
  The last Option worked for me while i had the same error at the time of installing Visual Studio